# USe Broadcast Receiver using service?

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

I am making an app in which I am receiving broadcast messages in a text box ...But the problem is that it is working only when that app is open now i want to get messages in text box and call web service when app is not open .So simply i want to make my app run in background.
 I have already created an app in which broadcast messages are coming in text box and they are also calling a web service now I want to run that app in background so that when message arrives then it should automatically put text in text box and call web service.

Comment: I have done everything in which i am receiving messages and also able to send that data to webservice...But when my application is closed then i am not able to call web service.....I HAVE USED BROADCAST RECEIVER TO GET MESSAGES....

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by first storing your sms in local sqlite database and then retrieve it in two edit box. So sms will be stored in local sqlite even if your application is not open and then call webservice.